# Can someone show me how to add this code to the rest of the code

Tags: javascript, html

My Code: https://jsfiddle.net/7meetm89/1/

This is the code, I don't know how to add it to the rest of the code, can someone show me?

```
myaud=document.getElementById("player");myaud.volume=1.0;
```

---

```
<button style="cursor: pointer; background-color:blue;padding-bottom:1px;"
onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>

<audio id="player" preload="none" style="display:none;">
<source src='http://air.radiorecord.ru:8101/rr_320' type='audio/mpeg'/>
</audio>
```

Comment: What are you expecting? Your audio is playing properly. You need earphone :)

Comment: what are you trying to do? Where's `play()` and `volume` from?

Comment: What do you mean, I'm trying to be able to set a volume setting, that's all. To be able to know how to do it, and what you posted wasn't correct.

Comment: What do you mean? Where's play() and volume from?

Comment: If you find yourself using more javascript I would recommend building functions rather than using inline scripts. `onclick="document.getElementById('player').play();document.getElementById('player').volume='1.0';"` Also a basic understanding of javascript will be helpful.  You only need to use `var` if you want to assign something element/value to a variable which will make your source code look clean and easy to read rather than having document.getElementById() over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one `function()` on `onclick`. Set volume and play controls inside that function.

**Additional Changes:** Added [controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#attr-controls) in audio tag to display HTML5 controls and removed `display:none`

**Edit:** You can add `setControls()` function inside `<script> </script>` tag. 
You can also add script in external file and link it. Please [read more](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp)

```js
function setControls() {
    myaud=document.getElementById("player");
    myaud.play();
    myaud.volume=1.0;
  }
```

```html
<button style="cursor: pointer; background-color:blue;padding-bottom:1px;"
onclick="setControls()">Play</button>

<audio controls id="player" preload="none">
<source src='http://air.radiorecord.ru:8101/rr_320' type='audio/mpeg'/>
</audio>
```

Comment: Great answer Rohit. I think **htmlcsscoding** is new to using javascript so maybe a quick edit on your answer to explain the use of `<script>` and where to place it on the page?

Comment: Please check this link. There are plenty of good doc, info and examples. Just ask uncle google.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Comment: Do controls have to be showing in order for that to work?

Comment: @htmlcsscoding No, the controls do not have to be showing.

Comment: @NewToJS, Added little explanation and link.

Comment: @NewToJS Can you show me it set up with the controls not  showing? This is with the controls showing https://jsfiddle.net/hm2skng7/ Can you show me it set up with the controls not showing?

Comment: @htmlcsscoding this should work just fine if you keep the style attribute on your audio tag. https://jsfiddle.net/hm2skng7/1/  **Rohit**, I will +1 for a detailed answer and relevant links to docs.

Comment: @NewToJS Would you be able to set that javascript up working with this code? https://jsfiddle.net/hm2skng7/7/ I tried but I'm confused on how to do it.

Comment: @htmlcsscoding what is the middle section for and why is it the buttons only appear after clicking?

Comment: @NewToJS It's a feature I added to it. The middle is just empty right now.

Comment: @htmlcsscoding I have expended on the answer given, I'm sure you can make changes to make it fit to how you want it. In this example I am removing the need of two buttons. The player is either playing or paused so I see no need for two buttons, you can use one and change the `innerHTML` https://jsfiddle.net/gbjph444/